# Close all ERC buffers

Tags: erc

I look for command to close all ERC related buffers, I couldn't find anything build-in. Does anyone implemented function like that or know how this function should look like?

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

- `M-x ibuffer` (this is my <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-b</kbd> binding)
- Either of these to mark the buffers of interest:

  - <kbd>*</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> `erc-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>
  - <kbd>%</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> `erc` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>D</kbd> to kill marked buffers

Comment: Do you know any way to make it single command?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I hacked something together some time ago.

The behavior of `+erc-quit` is to kill all buffers and child processes of `(erc-buffer-list)` without prompting for confirmation - it does this setting `kill-buffer-query-functions` to `nil`. If that doesn't fit you, just remove the list from the `let` binding.

```
(defun +erc-quit ()
    "Kill ERC buffers and terminate any child processes."
    (interactive)
    (let ((kill-buffer-query-functions nil)
          (erc-buffers (erc-buffer-list)))
      (if (not erc-buffers)
          (message "There are no ERC buffers to kill."))
      (progn
        (dolist (buffer erc-buffers)
          (kill-buffer buffer))
        (message "Killed all ERC buffers."))))
```