# get buffers list to startup state without resorting to M-x kill-emacs

Tags: buffer-list

Sometimes, when work is finished on one github/issues, its helpful to "reset" the list of opened files. So far I've been doing M-x kill-emacs and then restart,
but that's a bit heavy handed.

I tried [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3417473) , that did kill actual file buffers.
I want to to be able to reset things so that this kind of "miscellaneous" buffers aren't laying around:

[image: misc buffers]

`*scratch*` can stay, because it was there when emacs first started.

Comment: With `ibuffer` (which you seem to be using), you can group at least some of the buffers (e.g. the magit buffers) and deal with them in one blow - that should take care of 80% of the problem. See [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/63783/close-all-erc-buffers/63792#63792) example of dealing with ERC buffers,instead of magit buffers, but it should be close.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want all buffers that aren't scratch to be killed, correct?

Comment: What @coffeepenbit asked. It's not clear what OP means by *"this kind of 'miscellaneous' buffers"*.

Comment: (because they were there at emacs startup) what should remain is: `*scratch* *Messages* *Warnings**Compile-Log*`

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can quickly kill any or all buffers using just `C-x k`. Use one or more patterns (in the minibuffer) to match the buffers you want to kill, then use `C-!` to kill all those that match.

You can thus do this on the fly -- no need to open any special buffer, mark buffers etc. You can match using regexps, use multiple match patterns, etc.

See [Act On All Candidates](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Choose_All_Candidates).  See also [Buffer-Name Input](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Buffer-Name_Input).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I am going to assume you want to kill all buffers except `*scratch*`

This function does that:

```
(defun cpb-kill-all-buffers nil
  "Kill all buffers except *scratch*"
  (interactive)
  (mapcar 'kill-buffer (buffer-list))
  ;; Kill all other windows otherwise you will have many scratch windows.
  ;; reamining.
  (delete-other-windows))
```

Comment: what should remain: `*scratch* *Messages* *Warnings* *Compile-Log*`